# Styling nested rows conditionally in Handsontable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, handsontable

Using React wrapper for Handsontable. Data has nested child rows several levels deep.

Data looks like this:

```js
[
  {
    category: "Category A",
    subCategory: null,
    subItem: null,
    value: "abc 123",
    __children: [
      {
        category: null,
        subCategory: "Sub Category 1",
        subItem: null,
        value: "xyz 456",
      },
      {
        category: null,
        subCategory: "Sub Category 2",
        subItem: null,
        value: "qwe 987",
        __children: [
          {
            category: null,
            subCategory: null,
            subItem: "Sub Item I",
            value: "asd 987",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    category: "Category B",
    subCategory: null,
    subItem: null,
    value: "abc 345",
    __children: null,
  },
]
```

Let's say I need everything under "Category A" to be green but not under "Category B". How can that be done?

I tried passing a `cells` function `(row, col, prop) => {...}` but that gives me just the index of the row and column. The row index changes depending on what categories are collapsed. So, I need to be able to style the entire row based on the value of `category` of the parent row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite hard to implement the feature since almost all configurations are based on row and col indexes, the only workaround I found is to add the color along the value and use a custom renderer to evaluate when there is metadata in the string, you'll need to prepare your data beforehand

```js
const data = [
    {
      category: "Category A",
      subCategory: null,
      subItem: null,
      value: "abc 123#color:green",
      __children: [
        {
          category: "#color:green",
          subCategory: "Sub Category 1#color:green",
          subItem: null,
          value: "xyz 456"
        },
        {
          category: null,
          subCategory: "Sub Category 2",
          subItem: null,
          value: "qwe 987",
          __children: [
            {
              category: null,
              subCategory: null,
              subItem: "Sub Item I#color:green",
              value: "asd 987"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      category: "Category B",
      subCategory: null,
      subItem: null,
      value: "abc 345",
      __children: null
    }
  ];

...

const renderer = (instance, TD, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) => {
  TD.innerHTML = "";
  if (value) {
    if (value.indexOf("#color:") >= 0) {
      const [realValue, color] = value.split("#color:");
      TD.style.backgroundColor = color;
      TD.innerHTML = realValue;
    } else {
      TD.innerHTML = value;
    }
  }
  return TD;
};

...

      <HotTable
        data={data}
        colHeaders={true}
        rowHeaders={true}
        nestedRows={true}
        observeChanges
        renderer={renderer}
        licenseKey="non-commercial-and-evaluation"
      />
```

You can see it working here https://codesandbox.io/s/handsontable-epbpi?file=/src/index.tsx

Comment: Thanks. This works. But there is a strange behavior. When passing in an object `{label, color}` at the top category level, then label and color are treated as separate columns. Any idea why?

Comment: @markkazanski Jesus! so difficult to deal with this library hahaha, I don't have idea why it creates another column, so I came up with just another workaround, add the metadata as part of the string and split it to get the color, I updated answer and codesandbox, this kind of workaround could probably make some other features difficult for you but I don't see any other way :( even edition doesn't work, this will be useful to fix it https://handsontable.com/docs/8.1.0/tutorial-cell-editor.html